# Retrieving the same conditions for multiple rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, syntax

Working in SQL Server 2008, I need to retrieve the same information for comparison on all ID's below from the same table.

I have a list of Item IDs.

```
ABCD1234
ABCD5678
ABCD9101
ABCD5689
ABCD8796
```

How do I complete my WHERE clause most efficiently?

```
SELECT 
    [ItemID], [Value],
    [Division], [ItemGroup], [ProductName]
FROM 
    [DataQuality].[dbo].[TableQ]
WHERE 
    [ItemID]
```

Thanks!

Comment: share expected output

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of the `IN` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the SQL IN clause

```
SELECT [ItemID]
  ,[Value]
  ,[Division]
  ,[ItemGroup]
  ,[ProductName]
FROM [DataQuality].[dbo].[TableQ]
WHERE [ItemID] IN (
'ABCD1234',
'ABCD5678',
'ABCD9101',
'ABCD5689',
'ABCD8796'
)
```